# Counting Urn Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains eight red balls labeled 1-8, seven blue balls labeled 9-15 and five yellow balls labeled 16-20. Drawing balls with replacement from the urn, what is the probability the first yellow ball is drawn on the fifth draw?

I approached it like this:
There is a (3/4) chance in each trial of not getting yellow. Therefore the probability for not getting yellow on the first four tries, but getting it on the 5th should be (3/4)^4 * (1/4).

For some reason, this answer is wrong according to the book. Any ideas as to why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability the first $4$ are non-yellow is $\left(\frac{15}{20}\right)^4$.

Comment: I thought the answer should be (15/20)^4 * (5/20), which is approximately .079101625 but according to the answer key this is wrong. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your calculation is correct. If you tell me what the answer key says, I can maybe make a guess about what they did wrong. Perhaps they solved the "without replacement" problem.